# How to take a point (xn, yn) in the plane and maps it to a new point?

Tags: javascript, iteration

[image]

I tried to use the loop method but the program stuck.

```
function getPoints() {
  var x, y;

  for (
    x = 1, y = 2, a = 1.4, b = 0.3;
    x < 10, y < 10;
    x = 1 - a * x ** 2 + y, y = b * x
  ) {
    console.log(x, y);
  }
}
```

Comment: When should the loop end? Because now it never stops and clogs the main thread

Comment: @Ko if x=10 or y=10

Comment: can you describe in more detail what is your goal? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your `x` and `y` are negative after one iteration and continue to be negative in the next iterations

Comment: I would like to see how this system works and get a list with points (x,y) after a few iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to see how this system works and get a list with points (x,y) after a few iterations.

```js
function getPoints() {
  const a = 1.4,
    b = 0.3
  for (
    let i = 0, x = 1, y = 2; i < 10; i += 1
  ) {
    x = 1 - a * x ** 2 + y
    y = b * x
    console.log(x, y);
  }
}

getPoints()
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Konrad pointed out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75049620/how-to-take-a-point-xn-yn-in-the-plane-and-maps-it-to-a-new-point#comment132439242_75049620), `x` and `y` become negative and never again become positive, so the loop never ends. In this case, a better solution would be to use a while-loop and check for the absolute value of `x` and `y`, so the loop will terminate regardless of what direction the values go:

```js
let x = 1, y = 2
const a = 1.4, b = 0.3;

while (Math.abs(x) < 10 && Math.abs(y) < 10) {
  console.log(x, y)
  x = 1 - a * x ** 2 + y;
  y = b * x;
}
```

Also, note that your original for-loop does not do what you think it does. In the expression `x < 10, y < 10`, the comma does not mean *and*, it is a [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) and means *forget everything except the thing after the last comma*, which is `y < 10`. Expand the snippet below to see an example.

```js
for (
  let a = 0, b = 0;
  a < 10, b < 10;
  a += 2, b++
  ) {
  console.log(a, b)
  }
```